# Positioning a modal jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I have a modal `jframe` as a worker thread on top of another jframe with this code:

```
    final JDialog loading = new JDialog(this);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Please wait...", JLabel.CENTER);
    p1.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    loading.setUndecorated(true);
    loading.getContentPane().add(p1);
    loading.pack();
    loading.setSize(300,100); 
    loading.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    loading.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    loading.setModal(true);

    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
       /* code */
    };
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
       /* code */
    });
    worker.execute();
    loading.setVisible(true);
```

Issue is that java will place that "please wait..." window in the center of the parent. I want to put is in the bottom or somewhere else. I didn't find a position method for that. Please let me know if there exists such thing.

Comment: Centering the dialog is exactly what the [`setLocationRelativeTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) method is doing. If you want to place it at the bottom, use the [`setLocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocation-java.awt.Point-) method. First obtain the position of the parent frame with [`getLocationOnScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen--) and then subtract the size of your dialog to make it appear in the bottom edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `this` bounds (after it has been packed), calculate the required x,y and use `loading.setLocation(new Point(x,y));`